# #ORACLE / убедиться, что таблица нигде не используется, нет FK, нет триггеров и др

Tags: sql, oracle, table, constraints

Всем привет. 
Подскажите, пожалуйста, как убедиться, что таблица нигде больше не используется. 
Проверил по:

1. ALL_TRIGGERS
2. ALL_SOURCE
3. Проверил по коду в найденных процедурах в ALL_SOURCE.
4. Проверил Constraint-ы

Есть ли еще способы? 
Документации по системе нет. Экспертные разработчики уволились.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Проверьте зависимости:

```
select * from dba_dependencies where referenced_name = 'TABLE_NAME'
```

Если нет прав на `dba_dependencies`, можно попробовать `all_dependencies` или `user_dependencies`.
Ну и придётся проверить исходный код приложений. Тот, который в виде PL/SQL в БД, вы, видимо, уже проверили в `[dba|all|user]_source`.

Comment: Спасибо большое, в моем случае ничего не обнаружил там кроме 3 пакетов, в которых были процедуры найденные ранее. Но это как дополнительный источник для проверок такого рода.